# Get orientation of iphone created image email attachment

Tags: php

When I use the GD image library the orientation EXIF data is missing, is it possible to get the data straight from the raw data string before I use imagecreatefromstring() to make the jpg file? The orientation data is there because when I look at the email in gmail in chrome it shows the proper orientation, but as soon as I download the image that data is lost. I also tried using exif_thumbnail to see if I could figure out the orientation from that but the thumbnail is missing too.

If I download the attachment through chrome, windows image viewer displays it as landscape, but if I upload it to flickr it is displayed portrait, what is flickr using to determine orientation?

**EDIT: solved it**
createimagefromstring strips out a ton of meta data from the image file, but using fwrite creates the file verbatim from the data string, so I did this

```
$filename = 'pic.jpg';
$r = fopen($filename,'x');
fwrite($r,$raw_data); //$raw_data is the data string of the image
fclose($r);
```

and voila all the exif data was there! Stupid GD library! >:(

Answer (score 0):

If you're really using the GD library like you say you are, you can leverage [`getimagesize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to check for the image's dimensions. If the width is greater than the height of the image, you can safely assume that it was taken in landscape mode.

```
$params = getimagesize($image);
$width = $params[0];
$height = $params[1];

if ($width > $height) {
    $mode = "landscape";
} else if ($width < $height) {
    $mode = "portrait";
}
```

Comment: the thing about the iphone is that every picture is created landscape and there's an exif field 'orientation' that says what the orientation of the device was when the pic was taken. So getimagesize always returns values for a landscape image.